# python function to flag first 30% of transactions in a dataframe

Tags: python, function

I need to create a function or loop over a data frame which has 7000 rows of transactional data so I can find the first transactions taking place (in percentage groups).

The data has been ordered in ascending order by the date column as follows (using pySpark):

sorted_df = df.orderBy(asc(date))

I now need a function which will find and then create a flag in a new column for the first 30% of rows of data in the dataframe, so in this instance it will be the first 2100 rows (7000 * 0.3).
I would then like to improve this function to add additional flags to the rows which fall into the 40%, 50%, 60% transaction brackets
The next part of the question is to be able to apply this to a group of different months in the data (as for the above df I have filtered this down to one month data to make it easier to apply).
I am stuck here as I am new to creating functions and would like to use this as an opportunity to learn.
many thanks

Comment: What do you mean "flag"?

Comment: sorry I have amended the question slightly - I meant I would want the function to create a new column and basically flag "30%" for the rows of data which fall into this bracket, then the same for the others (40,50,60,% etc). thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
def flag_dataframe(df):
    df = df.reset_index() #to make sure the row index its still in the right order
    df.insert(len(df.columns), 'Flag', None) #create column flag
    flags = [30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100] #the flag percentages
    for i, row in df.iterrows(): #iterate through the dataframe, i is the index of the row, which is reset on the second line
        for flag in flags: 
            if(i / len(df) * 100 <= flag): #check which flag is the right flag
                df.loc[i, "flag"] = f"{flag}%" #setting the flag value of this row
                break #break out of this loop so it wont override the flag value for another one
    return df
```

example use:

```
df = flag_dataframe(df)
```

You could improve this by removing the flags list from the function and add it as parameter with some custom values. In this case I just used the flags you listed in your question.

For your question about how to apply this to a select number of rows (in this case records with the same month):

```
def flag_dataframe_by_month(df):
    df = df.reset_index() # to make sure the row index its still in the right order
    df.insert(len(df.columns), 'Flag', None) #create column flag
    flags = [30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100] #the flag percentages
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    for month in months:
        month_df = df[df["Month"] == month] #this will select all the rows from a month, but keep the index that is set on line 2
        month_df.insert(len(month_df.columns), 'month_rec_index', [i for i in range(len(month_df))]) #this will create an index based on the number of records with the same month, this index will not be used in the result
        for i, row in month_df.iterrows(): #iterate through the records with the same month, i is the index of the row in the original dataframe, which is set on line 2
            for flag in flags: 
                if(row["month_rec_index"] / len(month_df) * 100 < flag): #check which flag is the right flag
                    df.loc[i, "Flag"] = f"{flag}%" #setting the flag value of this row in the original dataframe
                    break #break out of this loop so it wont override the flag value for another one
    return df.drop(columns=["index"]) #pandas creates a second index, I dont exactly know why, but this is how to remove it again.
```

The usage is the same, if your months are named different or by index, just edit those in the month list.

I also edited some lines from my original answer, because those were giving warnings

Comment: Dear Wessel, Thank you so much for this - it is EXACTLY what I needed and now I can apply this myself next time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Dear Wessel, sorry I hope you don't mind me asking you a further question here but I think you can easily help me. Say I now had a huge dataframe - with many months worth of data and I wanted to perform this same action across each of the months in the dataframe, how would I implement that please? (As for the above I simplified the problem by filtering the initial dataframe to show just one month of data)

Comment: I don't mind, but I think its better to edit your question as well, to follow the rules of stackoverflow.

Comment: thanks so much Wessel, I will of course amend the question but I got in trouble for this previously in asking two questions at one time, and my question got closed